# Choosing boundary conditions for $(\frac{-d^2}{dx^2})^m$ on $H^m((0,1))$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

Consider the differential operator $D:$
$$
Du:=\frac{-d^2}{dx^2}u
$$
on the function space 
$$
C=\{u\in C^2([0,1]):u(0)=u(1)=0\}.
$$
It's not hard to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors(eigenfunctions) for $D$ by soloving the eigenvalue problem:
$$
-u''=\lambda u\qquad u(0)=u(1)=0.
$$

Here is my **question**:

> For each of the differential operators $D^m(m=2,3,4,\dots)$, what boundary conditions should one choose to ensure that $D^m$ and $D$ share the same [EDIT: set of] eigenfunctions?

---

**Added**(Thanks to Michael Renardy): Denote the boundary conditions for $D$ as $Lu=0$ and suppose that $Du=\lambda u$. Then we have
$$
D^{m}u=\lambda^mu
$$
and 
$$
L(D^ku)=L(\lambda^k u)=\lambda^k Lu=0\quad k =1,2,\cdots,m-1
$$
Now the problem reduce to show that if $D^mu=\lambda^m u$ and 
$$
L(D^ku)=0\quad k =1,2,\cdots,m-1
$$
then $Du=\lambda u$.